# Approximating exponentials in a nice to read format

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions, approximation

I need to make some approximations, basically I have something like

$$
e^{i*a} = -0.735145 + 0.67791*I 
$$

and I want to approximate  this to something that is easily readable, like

$$
e^{\frac{3*\pi}{2}*i}
$$

Does mathematica have a simplify function that can do this, while I specify the form of the equation I want to end up with (like the second one)? Is there another way, besides just taking a wild guess?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the documentation about [`Rationalize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rationalize.html)

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

Now starting from  the complex form you can build you own function

```
nicef = Exp[Rationalize[Im[Chop[Log[#]]], 1/16] I] &

nicef[-0.735145 + 0.67791 I]
```

> ```
> E^((12 I)/5)
> ```

or if the input is $a$ then just `Rationalize[a,1/16]`

Comment: Yes, I did try Rationalize, however my algorithm is so sensitive that not even with 0.000001 instead of 1/16, I won't get what I want. Anyway, your post does answer my question, so I will accept it. Thank you.